# How to set a value of HMTL checkbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

this my sound like a duplicate question asked 9 years ago but..
i need to set/assign a value to my check box. Simple stuff gender :

```html
<div>
  <label for="gender"><b>Gender:</b></label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male"   value="Male" required> Male
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="Female"> Female
</div>
<!-- #3 -->
<div>
  <label for="category"><b>Category</b></label>
  <input type="text"  name="category" id="category" required>
</div>
```

I manage to get data out (thanks guys), so its stored on localstorage; the json file is =

```
data = [ 'Miss', 'Female', 'Oversea'
       , '2001-06-10', 'sasha@gmail.com'
       , '39393939']
name = "Sasha"
```

now i need to retrieve the file to the above input form, edit and save. I need help to assign the value from the Json file to the html input.
I dont have a problem with the other fields; only the checkbox.
I resorted doing a if else statement;

```
function onEdit(td)
  {
  //obtain row index
  selectedRow = td.parentElement.parentElement;
  // Obtain name value (key)
  var name = selectedRow.cells[1].innerHTML;
  // goto local storage and get the data
  let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(name));

  document.getElementById("salutation").value = data[0];
  document.getElementById("name").value       = name;
  // // why why does this does not work
  //document.getElementById("gender").value     = data[1];
  // document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value = test;
  var test = data[1];
  if ((test) == "Male" )
    {
    document.getElementById('male').value = True;
    document.getElementById('female').value = False;
    }
  else
    {
    document.getElementById('male').value = False;
    document.getElementById('female').value = True;
    };
  document.getElementById("category").value   = data[2];
  document.getElementById("leaddob").value    = data[3];
  document.getElementById("leademail").value  = data[4];
  document.getElementById("leadtel").value    = data[5];
  }
```

but the check boxes do check but when i save the data it becomes blank.

Help!

Comment: Instead of `value` use `checked`

Comment: Thanks. it worked. need to change from True = true (False = false).

Answer (score 2):

don't use checked !

```js
const
  myForm = document.querySelector('#my-form')
, data  = { gender : 'Male' }
  ;
// init
myForm.gender.value = data.gender  // set Male checked, set Female unchecked

// get value
myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault() // disable submit for testing
  
  console.clear()
  console.log( 'myForm.gender =', myForm.gender.value )
  }
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Gender</legend>
    <label> <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"  > Male </label>   <!--label tag is around  the imput  -->
    <label> <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"> Female</label>   <!--  any click on text part set box cheked -->
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit"> submit </button>
</form>
```

Input element have their own mecanism within Form